# making HTTPS work on LAN with self signed certificate

Tags: https, encryption, self-signed-certificate

This is on a local area network (LAN).  There is no internet connection.  One admin has admin access to both the linux server and windows10 pc's.

I have a linux server running third party software to establish an over-the-network OpenGL remote visualization connection.

Win10 pc's as the client connect to the server using a web browser, or with their portable client.  The default configuration is to connect via `https://myserver:8443` using the browser.

In doing so with a browser one gets the traditional *your data is at risk* or in Firefox it is *Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead.*  And then you click on advanced and say *Accept the Risk and Continue* which (correct me if i'm wrong) establishes a **not secure** https connection.

I start with trying to create a self signed certificate?

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout private.pem -out public.pem -days 365
```

and per my software's instructions put these two pem files under their folder */etc/dcv/* and the software will use them instead of *automatically generating a self-signed certificate that is used to secure traffic.*  However I am not sure what the ownership and permissions on these files should be {i thought private.pem was important to protect}

**This is where I hit a wall**

I found how to combine the *private.pem* and *public.pem* file into a **PKCS#12 (P12) bundle:**

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey private.pem -in public.pem -export -out certificate.p12
```

however I am prompted to password protect this certificate.p12 file,
and then i can import it into my web browser but having to type the password to do so.  That seemed to make a secure https connection work one time because their was not an https red padlock it was green, but I feel like at this point I and doing something wrong.  It feels wrong to bundle private.pem with public.pem and distribute ?  Do I need to import anything into my client pc's browser under *Trusted Root Authority*?  If someone can explain in practical terms how it should be done for this kind of LAN scenario would be much appreciated.  I am not looking to do anything *official* such as purchase a certificate, it's just a few computers on a LAN with no internet connection.

Comment: Yes, the browser or other client does not need and normally should not have the privatekey. Instead of creating a PKCS12, copy _just_ the self-signed cert (your `public.pem`) and import _that_ to the 'trusted root' store on each client/browser. (You can actually use a cert in either PEM format or what OpenSSL calls DER (binary) format, but PEM is what you have in this case and is generally more convenient anyway.)